# Schreibrecht vs. Schreiberecht

Tags: noun, compound

Jahrelang schreiben Computernetnutzer freudig und glücklich „Schreibrecht“.  Beispiel:

> Schreiben – der User kann die Datei modifizieren. Das *Schreibrecht* für ein Verzeichnis bedeutet, dass der Benutzer die Dateien im Verzeichnis anlegen und löschen kann.

(Quelle: https://geek-university.com/linux-deutsch/arten-von-zugriffsrechten )

Heute starrte ich das Wort in einem ähnlichen Computer-Kontext etwas länger an, denn ich überlegte, wie Bertolt Brecht schrie und was ein Schrei-Brecht mit meinem Dateisystem zu tun haben könnte.

Dann grübelte ich nach, warum es „Leserecht“ und nicht „Lesrecht“ heißt. Ich kam zu keinem guten Schluss über die Logik des Deutschen. Natürlich kann man die von unbekannten Geeks kompilierten Wortlisten inspizieren, rein statistisch begründete Aussagen treffen (nach „Schreib“ kommt meistens kein Fugen-e und nach „Les“ kommt meistens ein Fugen-e) und mit sich dem emotionslosen *Es hat sich so eingebürgert* zufriedengeben, aber keine dieser statistisch begründeten Gepflogenheiten ist ohne Ausnahme.

Daher: sollte ein Recht, Dateien oder Verzeichnisse in einem Dateisystem zu beschreiben, nicht vllt. Schreib**e**recht heißen?  Mit dem Fugenlaut „-e-“ kommt das Wort zwar seltener vor, steht aber genauso wenig bei Duden/Wahrig wie das Wort ohne den Fugenlaut. Oder gibt es sonstige Einwände, die ich nicht sehe, gegen „Schreiberecht“, außer der Seltenheit?

Comment: Kommt mir insgesamt nicht besonders plausibel vor. Müsste der Schreibtisch dann nicht auch zum Schreibetisch werden?

Comment: Es wäre dann analog (und sogar auch ein Reim) zu "Bleiberecht". Und zu "Leserecht" würde es zugegebenermaßen auch ganz gut passen. Aber dass sich da eine *Verpflichtung* konstruieren lässt, das Kompositum als "Schreiberecht" statt "Schreibrecht" zu bilden, bezweifle ich.

Answer (score 1):

Zum Einwand 1 von besc fallen mir spontan ein

- Schreibschrift
- Schreibmaschine
- Schreibwettbewerb
- Schreibstube
- Schreibmappe

bzw.

- Lesebrille
- Lesezirkel
- Leseratte
- Lesehilfe

Dadurch ist natürlich noch keine Regel definiert. Aber Just_A-Man grübelte ja über die Logik, und eine gewisse Logik, lässt sich da schon erkennen

Comment: Interessanter Aspekt! Besonders die Beispiele mit Rechtschreibung. Ich hätte fast gesagt, dass es nur meine Umgangssprache ist, die dort das "e" weglässt, und fand dann aber das hier: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln